# How to specify the number of seconds a patch will record data about turtle flow?

Tags: netlogo

I  have the code:

```
   set number-of-cars-passing-point count turtles-here 

    set list total-car-number lput number-of-cars-passing-point
  end
```

and this will be applied to one patch on each road within my network. Using this I want to be able to calculate the flow of cars along a road (the number of different cars that were present on a patch in a given time period). How can I state the time that the patch will record the number of turtles on it so that I can calculate traffic flow?

Answer (score 0):

Say 1 unit sec = 1 unit tick and you wish to record every 10 secs.

```
if(remainder ticks 10 = 0)[
set number-of-cars-passing-point count turtles-here 
set list total-car-number lput number-of-cars-passing-point
]
```